# Cursor won't change when mousing over element

Tags: html, css

I have a "menu_toggle" div that should change the mouse cursor when I mouse over it. Usually this is relatively simple however when I add cursor:pointer; to my CSS it does not work. I have tried changing its Z-index so that it is on top but this has not fixed the issue.

I will include code snippets below. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

```css
#navbar {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index: 10;
}
#navbar_content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: centre;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95%;
}
#logo {
    align-self: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}
#logo img {
    max-height: 64px;
}
#menu_toggle {
    align-self: center;
    display: block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    z-index: -1;
}
#slideoutmenu {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: white;
    font-family: "Liberation Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <div id="navbar_content">
                <div id="menu_toggle"><img style="max-height: 64px;" src="images/menu_icon.png"/></div>
                <div id="slideoutmenu">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>    
                    <ul>
                        <li>Design</li>
                        <li>Development</li>
                        <li>See My Work</li>
                        <li>About Me</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the _cursor:pointer_ here ? Also what do yu want the cursor ro turn into!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` work only when applied with position `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

```
#menu_toggle {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I tried that before and it still isn't working. Here is the link the website if you want to take a look? [Website](www.nthompson.net)

Comment: @user6419974 this is not the `cursor: pointer` issue. Its z-index issue. If you will set `#navbar {z-index: 11;}` this issue will be fixed. Because `.launchpanelcontent` have `z-index: 10` and its overlapping your `#navbar`

Comment: Thanks for that I thought I had set the z-index's differently hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use a `div` for this purpose. Use `a` for `#menu_toggle` instead. The additional benefit is that `a` already has the "pointer" cursor by default (if used with `href`).

As a side note, divs are not accessible using the tab key unless you specify `tabindex` manually.

Comment: Good point and it should be `button` or `a` but sometimes in single page applications where we do not redirect to other pages, If we use `a` then we need to cancel default behavior for each one. But if we use `span` or `div` with `cursor: pointer`, it results in shorter code if project is very large...

Comment: @MuhammadUsman You can still ommit the `href` attribute and specify `a { cursor: pointer }` then...

Comment: yes, its possible too but in this way there won't be any difference between `a` or `span` as both are inline and can be used interchangeably

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Besides, if you use anything other than `a` tags or buttons, you have to set `tabindex` manually on the element for keyboard users to be able to access it. If one thing needs to be accessible, it is menus.

Answer (score 0):

You have a negative z-index. That puts it outside the reach of the cursor.

```
#menu_toggle {
    align-self: center;
    display: block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    z-index: 1; /** Change to positive value */
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this:

## **test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Menu Design</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>


<ul id="menu_table" class="menu_menulist css_menu" style="width: 163px; height: 60px;">
  <li class="topitem spaced_li"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient60"><a class="button_1">Link1</a></div></li>
  <li class="topitem"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient60" style="width: 89px;"><div class="arrow"><a>Link2</a></div></div>
  <ul>
  <li><a title="">SubLink1</a></li>
  <li><a title="">SubLink2</a></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu/style.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Inside of menu Folder Create these two files.**

**style.css**

```
#menu_table {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu_table li a {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI",sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 20px 35px 20px 20px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu_table li div.buttonbg {
  height: 60px;
  width: 74px;
  line-height: 0;
  background-color: #0071BB;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu_table li:hover div.buttonbg a, #menu_table li.expanded a.topitem, #menu_table li.active a.topitem,
#menu_table li.itemhot a.topitem, #menu_table li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#menu_table li.expanded div.buttonbg, #menu_table li.active div.buttonbg, #menu_table li.itemhot div.buttonbg, #menu_table li:hover div.buttonbg {
  background-color: #74D214;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

#menu_table {
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

#menu_table ul li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu_table ul li:hover > a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu_table ul li.subexpanded a.subexpanded, #menu_table ul li.subitemhot a.subitemhot, #menu_table ul li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu_table ul li:hover, #menu_table ul li.subexpanded, #menu_table ul li.subitemhot {
  border-color: #CC0000;
  background-color: #CC0000;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#menu_table ul {
  margin: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000000;
  font-size: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#menu_table ul li a {
  padding: 7px 15px 7px 13px;
  text-align: left;
}

#menu_table ul li.separator {
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: default;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-width: 0;
}

#menu_table ul li.separator div {
  border-top: 1px solid #646464;
  font-size: 0px;
}

#menu_table ul li {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 0 0px 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #000000;
}


#menu_table .spaced_li {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#menu_table a img {
  border: none;
}

#menu_table li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

#menu_table.css_menu li {
  position: relative;
}

#menu_table.css_menu ul li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu_table.css_menu li:hover > ul {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu_table.css_menu ul li:hover > ul {
  top: -0px;
  left: 100%;
  right: auto;
}

#menu_table.css_menu ul {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property:opacity;
  -webkit-transition-property:opacity;
  -moz-transition-property:opacity;
  -ms-transition-property:opacity;
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu_table ul {
  position: absolute;
  top:-99999px;
  z-index: 4000;
}

#menu_table ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5000;
}

#menu_table .submenu_arrow {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#menu_table div.arrow { 
  background-image: url(ebab_mbmcp_d.png); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: right center; 
  height: 100%; 
} 

#menu_table ul li a.with_arrow { 
  background-image: url(ebab_mbmcp_c.png); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: right center; 
  padding-right: 19px; 
} 

#menu_table div.gradient60 { 
  background-image: url('button_bg.png'); 
  background-repeat: repeat-x; 
  background-color: #026199; 
} 

#menu_table li:hover div.gradient60, #menu_table li.expanded div.gradient60, #menu_table li.active div.gradient60, #menu_table li.itemhot div.gradient60 { 
  background-image: none; 
  background-color: #74D214; 
} 

#menu_table div.gradient_button { 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0273BB 0%, #026199 100%); 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0273BB 0%, #026199 100%); 
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0273BB 0%, #026199 100%); 
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0273BB 0%, #026199 100%); 
} 

#menu_table li a.button_1, #menu_table li div a.button_1 { 
  padding-right: 20px; 
}
```

**style.js**

```
function IsAllDefined(){for(var a=0;a<arguments.length;++a){if(typeof(arguments[a])=="undefined"){return false}}return true}function asNum(a){return parseInt(a,10)||0}function getStyleAsNum(d,b,e){var c="0";if(document.defaultView&&document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){c=asNum(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(d,"").getPropertyValue(b))}else{if(d.currentStyle){c=asNum(d.currentStyle[e])}}return asNum(c)}function GetWinH(){var b=0;var a=0;if((!document.compatMode||document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat")&&document.documentElement){a=document.documentElement}else{if(document.body){a=document.body}}if(a&&a.clientHeight){b=a.clientHeight}else{if(IsAllDefined(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight,document.width)){b=window.innerHeight;if(document.width>window.innerWidth){b=b-15}}}return b}function GetWinW(){var a=0;var b=0;if((!document.compatMode||document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat")&&document.documentElement){b=document.documentElement}else{if(document.body){b=document.body}}if(b&&b.clientWidth){a=b.clientWidth
}else{if(IsAllDefined(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight,document.height)){a=window.innerWidth;if(document.height>window.innerHeight){a=a-15}}}return a}function GetObjectRect(e){var a=0;var g=0;var f=e;var c=false;while(e&&e!=null){if(e.style&&e.style.position=="fixed"){c=true}a+=asNum(isNS4?e.pageX:e.offsetLeft);g+=asNum(isNS4?e.pageY:e.offsetTop);if(isNS4){if(e.style&&(e.style.position=="absolute"||e.style.position=="relative")){break}}e=e.offsetParent}e=f;var b=0;var d=0;if(isOp&&!isOp7){b=e.style.pixelWidth}else{if(isNS4){b=e.clip.width}else{b=e.offsetWidth}}if(isOp&&!isOp7){d=e.style.pixelHeight}else{if(isNS4){d=e.clip.height}else{d=e.offsetHeight}}return{x:a,y:g,w:b,h:d,in_fixed:c}}function LoadSrcImage(b){var a=new Image();if(typeof isIE=="undefined"){GetBrowserInfo()}if(isIE&&window.location.protocol=="file:"){a.meSrc=b}else{a.src=b}return a}function GetBrowserInfo(){isDOM=document.getElementById;isMz=isDOM&&(navigator.appName=="Netscape");isOp=isDOM&&window.opera;isIE=document.all&&document.all.item&&!isOp;
isIE6orLess=false;isIE8orLess=false;if(isIE){var a=navigator.userAgent;var b=new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[.0-9]{0,})");if(b.exec(a)!=null){var c=parseFloat(RegExp.$1);isIE6orLess=(c<=6);isIE8orLess=(c<=8)}}isIE9=isIE&&document.documentMode>=9;isNS4=document.layers;isOp7=isOp&&document.readyState}function GetViewRect(){var c=0;var a=0;if(isNS4||isMz||isOp){a=window.pageXOffset;c=window.pageYOffset}else{var b=(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"&&!isMz)?document.documentElement:document.body;a=b.scrollLeft;c=b.scrollTop}return{x:a,y:c,w:GetWinW(),h:GetWinH()}}function SetElemOpacity(a,b){if(a&&a.style){if(b==1){a.style.opacity=((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Gecko")>-1)&&!/Konqueror|Safari|KHTML/.test(navigator.userAgent))?0.999999:1;if(isIE&&!isIE9){if(a.style.filter){a.style.filter=a.style.filter.replace(/alpha\([^\)]*\)/gi,"")}}}else{if(b<0.00001){b=0}a.style.opacity=b;if(isIE&&!isIE9){a.style.filter=(a.style.filter?a.style.filter.replace(/alpha\([^\)]*\)/gi,""):"")+"alpha(opacity="+b*100+")"
}}}}function SetElementScale(d,m,l){if(d&&d.style){try{if(m>1){m=1}if(l>1){l=1}if(isIE&&!isIE9){if(m==1&&l==1){d.style.filter=d.style.filter.replace(/progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix\([^\)]*\);?/gi,"")}else{var c=0;var b=0;if(d.cbnDirectionX==-1&&d.cbnMenuRect){c=d.cbnMenuRect.w-d.cbnMenuRect.w*m}if(d.cbnDirectionY==-1&&d.cbnMenuRect){b=d.cbnMenuRect.h-d.cbnMenuRect.h*l}m=Math.round(m*100)/100;l=Math.round(l*100)/100;d.style.filter=(d.style.filter?d.style.filter.replace(/progid\:DXImageTransform\.Microsoft\.Matrix\([^\)]*\)/gi,""):"")+"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='clip to original', M11="+m+", M12=0, M21=0, M22="+l+" Dx="+c+" Dy="+b+")"}}else{var k="0";var h="0";if(d.cbnDirectionX==-1){k="100%"}if(d.cbnDirectionY==-1){h="100%"}if(d.ebnStyleScaleProperty){a=d.ebnStyleScaleProperty}else{var a=null;var j=["transform","MozTransform","WebkitTransform","OTransform","msTransform"];for(var f=0;f<j.length;f++){if(d.style[j[f]]!=null){a=j[f];break}}d.ebnStyleScaleProperty=a
}if(a!=null){if(m==1&&l==1){d.style[a]=""}else{d.style[a]="scale("+m+","+l+")";d.style[a+"Origin"]=k+" "+h}}}}catch(g){}}}function ebmResetElementScale(a){SetElementScale(a,1,1)}function ebmProgressElementScale(b,a){if(b.ebmScaleEffect==1){SetElementScale(b,1,a)}else{if(b.ebmScaleEffect==2){SetElementScale(b,a,a)}else{if(b.ebmScaleEffect==3){SetElementScale(b,a,1)}}}}function ebmSetDivShadow(e,b,a){var f=null;var d=["boxShadow","MozBoxShadow","WebkitBoxShadow"];for(var c=0;c<d.length;c++){if(e.style[d[c]]!=null){f=d[c];break}}if(f==null){if(isIE){e.style.filter+="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX="+b+", OffY="+a+", Color='#80777777', Positive='true')";return true}else{return false}}return true}function ebmStartTimer(a){var b=setTimeout(function(){ebmRemoveSubmenu(a)},550);return b}function ebmTickerOn(b){var c;for(var a=b;a;a=a.openSubmenuDiv){c=a;if(!a.ticker){a.ticker=ebmStartTimer(c)}}}function ebmTickerOff(b){for(var a=b;a;a=a.upperTR?a.upperTR.menuDiv:0){if(a.ticker){clearTimeout(a.ticker);
a.ticker=0}}}function ebmMenuPosY(b,j,i,d,h,g,e){var a=5;var f=i;var k=h;var c=g;if(k>j-2*a&&j>0){f=a+b;k=j-2*a}else{if(c==-1){f=i+d-k+e}else{f=i}if(f<b+a){f=b+a;c=1}if(f+h>j+b-a&&j>0){f-=f+k-(j+b-a);c=-1}}return{y:f,direction:c,size:k}}function ebmMenuPosX(c,d,i,k,b,h,f){var a=5;var g=i;var j=b;var e=h;if(((e>=0)&&(i+k+b>d+c-a))||((e<0)&&(i-b<a))){if(i-c>d+c-(i+k)&&d>0){e=-1}else{e=1}}if(e>=0){g=i+k;if(d+c-a-g<j&&d>0){j=d+c-a-g}}else{g=i-j+f;if(g-c<a){g=c+a;j=i-(c+a)}}return{x:g,direction:e,size:j}}function ebmFade(b){if(b){var a=new Date().getTime();var d=a-b.cbnLastAnimTime;var c=d/200;if(c<0.05||b.cbnTransitionProgress==0){c=0.05}b.cbnTransitionProgress=c;if(b.cbnTransitionProgress>1){b.cbnTransitionProgress=1}if(b.ebmFadeEffect){var e=b.cbnTransitionProgress;if(b.cbnMenuAlpha&&e>b.cbnMenuAlpha){e=b.cbnMenuAlpha}SetElemOpacity(b,e)}if(b.ebmScaleEffect>0){ebmProgressElementScale(b,b.cbnTransitionProgress)}if(b.cbnTransitionProgress>=1){clearInterval(b.ebmFadeTimer);b.ebmFadeTimer=null
}}}function ebmHideSubmenus(){if(cbnOpenTopMenu){ebmRemoveSubmenu(cbnOpenTopMenu)}}function ebmDisplaySubmenu(h,c,f){var e=h;if(e&&e.style){if(e.style.display=="block"){ebmTickerOff(e);return}e.style.display="block";e.style.left="0px";e.style.top="0px";e.style.height="auto";e.style.width="auto";if(!e.depth&&(cbnOpenTopMenu!=e)){ebmRemoveSubmenu(cbnOpenTopMenu)}if(c&&c.menuDiv&&c.menuDiv.openSubmenuDiv&&c.menuDiv.openSubmenuDiv!=e){ebmRemoveSubmenu(c.menuDiv.openSubmenuDiv)}ebmTickerOff(e);if(e.depth>0){e.cbnDirectionX=e.upperTR.menuDiv.cbnDirectionX;e.cbnDirectionY=e.upperTR.menuDiv.cbnDirectionY}else{e.cbnDirectionX=e.cbnDefaultDirectionX;e.cbnDirectionY=1}e.style.overflow="visible";var b=c;if(b.tagName&&b.tagName.toLowerCase()=="a"){b=b.parentNode}var a=GetObjectRect(b);var i=0;var j=GetObjectRect(e);var g=GetViewRect();if(j.in_fixed){g.x=0;g.y=0}var d;if(f){d=ebmMenuPosY(g.y,g.h,a.y,a.h,j.h,e.cbnDirectionY,0)}else{d=ebmMenuPosX(g.y,g.h,a.y,a.h,j.h,e.cbnDirectionY,0);d.y=d.x}e.cbnDirectionY=d.direction;
e.style.top=d.y-j.y+"px";j=GetObjectRect(e);if(f){d=ebmMenuPosX(g.x,g.w,a.x,a.w,j.w,e.cbnDirectionX,i)}else{d=ebmMenuPosY(g.x,g.w,a.x,a.w,j.w,e.cbnDirectionX,i);d.x=d.y}e.cbnDirectionX=d.direction;if((d.size<j.w)&&(e.cbnDirectionX>0)){d.x=d.x-(j.w-d.size)}e.style.left=d.x-j.x+"px";e.cbnMenuRect={w:j.w,h:j.h,x:d.x-j.x,y:d.y-j.y};if(e.ebmFadeEffect||ebmScaleEffect>0){if(!e.ebmFadeTimer){if(e.ebmFadeEffect){SetElemOpacity(e,0.05)}if(e.ebmScaleEffect>0){ebmProgressElementScale(e,0.05)}e.cbnTransitionProgress=0;e.cbnLastAnimTime=new Date().getTime();e.ebmFadeTimer=setInterval(function(){ebmFade(e)},20)}}if(!e.depth){cbnOpenTopMenu=e}else{c.menuDiv.openSubmenuDiv=e}e.style.display="block"}}function ebmRemoveSubmenu(b){var a=b;if(a&&(a.style.display=="block")){if(a.openSubmenuDiv){ebmRemoveSubmenu(a.openSubmenuDiv)}if(a.upperTR&&a.upperTR.className){a.upperTR.makeNormal()}a.style.display="none";a.openSubmenuDiv=0;if(a.ticker){clearTimeout(a.ticker);a.ticker=null}if(a.ebmFadeEffect||a.ebmScaleEffect){if(a.ebmFadeEffect){SetElemOpacity(a,0)
}if(ebmScaleEffect>0){ebmResetElementScale(a)}if(a.ebmFadeTimer){clearTimeout(a.ebmFadeTimer);a.ebmFadeTimer=null}}}}function ebmAddRemoveClass(e,g,f,d){if(d){e.className=e.className.replace(" "+f,"")}else{if(e.className.indexOf(f)==-1){e.className+=" "+f}}for(var c=0;c<g.length;c++){var b=e.firstChild;while(g[c]&&b){if(b.nodeName.toLowerCase()==g[c]){ebmAddRemoveClass(b,g,f,d)}b=b.nextSibling}}}function ebmGenerateTree(menuUL,upperTR,depth,className,idName){var re=/^([a-zA-Z]*?\:\/\/)?[^\(\)\:]*?(\?.*)?$/;var rejs=/^(javascript\:)/;var li=menuUL.firstChild;while(li){if(li.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="li"){if(depth!=0){var itemLink=li.firstChild;while(itemLink){if(itemLink.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="a"){if(itemLink.href&&(!itemLink.target||itemLink.target.toLowerCase()=="_self")){itemLink.onclick=function(e){if(!e){var e=window.event}e.cancelBubble=true;if(e.stopPropagation){e.stopPropagation()}};if(itemLink.href.match(re)){li.rowClickLink=itemLink.href;li.onclick=function(){window.location.href=this.rowClickLink;
return false}}else{if(itemLink.href.match(rejs)){li.rowClickLink=itemLink.href;li.onclick=function(){eval(this.rowClickLink)}}}}else{if(!itemLink.href){li.onclick=function(){if(this.assocmenu){this.makeExpanded();ebmDisplaySubmenu(this.assocmenu,this,1)}}}}}itemLink=itemLink.nextSibling}}else{ebmAddRemoveClass(li,["a","div"],"topitem",false)}if(depth!=0){li.onmouseover=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a"],"subitemhot",false);if(this.assocmenu){this.makeExpanded();ebmDisplaySubmenu(this.assocmenu,this,1)}};li.onmouseout=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a"],"subitemhot",true);if(this.assocmenu){meDoMouseOut(this.assocmenu)}};li.makeExpanded=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a"],"subexpanded",false)};li.makeNormal=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a"],"subexpanded",true)}}else{var lia;var itemLink=li.firstChild;while(itemLink){if(itemLink.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="a"){lia=itemLink}itemLink=itemLink.nextSibling}if(lia){lia.parentli=li;var imgOver=false;var imgDown=false;var img=lia.firstChild;
while(img){if(img.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="img"){if(img.className=="normalbutton"){lia.imgNormal=img;lia.imgNormalSrc=img.src}if(img.className=="hoverbutton"){lia.imgOverSrc=img.src;imgOver=img}if(img.className=="downbutton"){lia.imgDownSrc=img.src;imgDown=img}}img=img.nextSibling}if(imgOver){lia.removeChild(imgOver)}if(imgDown){lia.removeChild(imgDown)}if(!lia.href){lia.onmouseover=function(){if(this.assocmenu){meDoShow(this.assocmenu,this.ebmMenuDirection,this)}}}lia.onmouseover=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this.parentli,["a","div"],"itemhot",false);if(this.imgNormal&&this.imgOverSrc){var link=this.imgOverSrc;if(isIE&&(window.location.protocol!="file:")){link+="#"}this.imgNormal.src=link}};lia.onmouseout=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this.parentli,["a","div"],"itemhot",true);ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a","div"],"itemdown",true);if(this.imgNormal&&this.imgNormalSrc){this.imgNormal.src=this.imgNormalSrc}};lia.onmousedown=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a","div"],"itemdown",false);if(this.imgNormal&&this.imgDownSrc){this.imgNormal.src=this.imgDownSrc
}};lia.onmouseup=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a","div"],"itemdown",true);if(this.imgNormal&&this.imgOverSrc){this.imgNormal.src=this.imgOverSrc}else{if(this.imgNormal&&this.imgNormalSrc){this.imgNormal.src=this.imgNormalSrc}}}}li.onmouseover=function(){if(this.assocmenu){meDoShow(this.assocmenu,this.ebmMenuDirection,this)}};li.onmouseout=function(){if(this.imgNormal&&this.imgNormalSrc){this.imgNormal.src=this.imgNormalSrc}if(this.assocmenu){meDoMouseOut(this.assocmenu)}};li.makeExpanded=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a","div"],"expanded",false)};li.makeNormal=function(){ebmAddRemoveClass(this,["a","div"],"expanded",true)}}li.menuDiv=menuUL;var ul=li.firstChild;while(ul){if(ul.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="ul"){ul.onmouseout=function(){meDoMouseOut(this)};ul.onmouseover=function(){meDoMouseOver(this)};ul.ebmFadeEffect=ebmFadeEffect;if(depth==0){ul.cbnMenuAlpha=cbnMenuAlpha}if(ebmFadeEffect){SetElemOpacity(ul,0)}else{if(cbnMenuAlpha){SetElemOpacity(ul,ul.cbnMenuAlpha)}}ul.ebmScaleEffect=ebmScaleEffect;
if(ebmScaleEffect>0){ebmResetElementScale(ul)}ul.cbnDefaultDirectionX=cbnDefaultDirectionX;ul.upperTR=li;ul.depth=depth;ul.openSubmenuDiv=0;li.assocmenu=ul;li.ebmMenuDirection=ebmMenuDirection;ebmGenerateTree(ul,li,depth+1,className,idName);break}ul=ul.nextSibling}}li=li.nextSibling}}function meDoShow(d,b,c){var a=d;if(a&&a.style){c.makeExpanded();ebmTickerOff(cbnOpenTopMenu);ebmDisplaySubmenu(a,c,b)}}function meDoMouseOut(a){if(a){ebmTickerOn(cbnOpenTopMenu)}}function meDoMouseOver(a){if(a){ebmTickerOff(a)}}function InitEasyMenu(){GetBrowserInfo();if(isMz&&!cbnMenuAlpha&&!ebmFadeEffect){cbnMenuAlpha=1}if(isIE8orLess){cbnMenuAlpha=0}var a=document.getElementsByTagName("ul");for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++){if(a[b].id&&a[b].id==ebmMenuName+"ebul_table"&&a[b].className.substr(0,ebmMenuName.length+13)==ebmMenuName+"ebul_menulist"){if(isIE6orLess){a[b].style.overflow="hidden"}ebmGenerateTree(a[b],0,0,ebmMenuName+"ebul_menulist","ebul_"+ebmMenuName+"_mdiv");a[b].className=a[b].className.replace("css_menu","")
}}}var cbnOpenTopMenu=0;var cbnMenuAlpha = 0;var ebmFadeEffect = true;var ebmScaleEffect = 0;var ebmMenuDirection = 0;var ebmMenuName = "mbmcp";var cbnDefaultDirectionX = 1;InitEasyMenu();
```